# Conversion of CIImage to CGImageRef which could be used to create a GLK texture

Tags: ios, cgimageref, ciimage, glktextureloader

I have a CIImage which is the result/output image of a CIFilter. Now I want to create a texture of that image using GLKTextureLoader. I am using the following function which requires a CGImageRef to achieve that.

```
[GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage: options: error:];
```

So the question is, what is the best way to convert a CIImage to CGImageRef which could be used by GLKTextureLoader?

I tried the following method but it failed:

```
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CGImageRef ref = [context createCGImage:fullScreenCI fromRect:fullScreenCI.extent];
self.info = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:ref options:nil error:&error];
```

*fullscreenCI* is the outputImage of a CIFilter.

The above method gives the following error:

**error in creating GLK texture : Error Domain=GLKTextureLoaderErrorDomain Code=12 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (GLKTextureLoaderErrorDomain error 12.)" UserInfo=0x1438a880 {GLKTextureLoaderErrorKey=Image decoding failed}**

I figured out it could be because of some colorspace issue and tried the following method:

```
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CGImageRef ref = [context createCGImage:fullScreenCI fromRect:fullScreenCI.extent];
fullscreen = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref])];
self.info = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:fullscreen.CGImage options:nil error:&error];
```

Now the above method works fine! But I want to know if there is any better way to convert the CIImage to CGImageRef without having to use UIImagePNGRepresentation.

Comment: did you try the `[CIContext createCGImage:fromRect:format:colorSpace:]` method?

Comment: @JonathanCichon Could you please tell me what parameters should I pass for 'format' and 'colorSpace'? I tried passing the constant 'kCIFormatARGB8' for format and CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB() for colorSpace. But got the same error which I got when I used [CIContext createCGImage:(CIImage *) fromRect:(CGRect)].

Comment: I see the exact same problem. I'll do more research, but I think this is a bug.